# Need Help displaying Core Data in a UITableView in Swift

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift2

Please forgive if this is a duplicate question. I did search as thoroughly as I could, but none of the other questions that I've seen regarding core data in a UITableView seem to quite fit what I am trying to do.

Basically, I have two "tables" in my Core Data:

cstProjects and plProjects

Both tables have attributes called "propertyOwner" and "propertyID" (among others), that are set as Strings.

Next, in a ViewController, I have a table view instance, with the style set to Subtitle, and the cell identifier set to "projectCell".

Because I have two tables in my core data, I initialize the table to having two sections. I would like the first section to show all of the projects in the cstProjects table, and the second section to show all of the projects in the plProjects table.

Here is my ViewController code so far. I've put comments in, to explain it as best as I can. The functions that I have created might be a bit overkill to figure out how many "rows" each section should have, but I didn't know of a simpler way of going about it.

In the code below, where you see the double question marks "??" is where I am not sure what to put in order to show the current "row" of the type of project that we're currently iterating through.

Ultimately though, if I had to simplify my question down as much as possible, I just need to know how to show the rows of a core data table in a UITableView.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class LoadProjectViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    let projectSectionCount: Int = 2
    let cstSection: Int = 0
    let plSection: Int = 1

    // Implement UITableViewDataSource methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return projectSectionCount
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch(section) {
        case cstSection:
            return getCSTProjects()
        case plSection:
            return getPLProjects()
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("projectCell")! as UITableViewCell

        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case cstSection:
                //this is where I need to set the property owner for the CST Project
                cell.textLabel!.text = ??

                //this is where I need to set the project ID for the CST Project
                cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ??
            case plSection:
                //this is where I need to set the property owner for the PL Project
                cell.textLabel!.text = ??

                //this is where I need to set the project ID for the PL Project
                cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ??

            default:
                cell.textLabel!.text = "Unknown"
        }

        return cell
     }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch section {
            case cstSection:
                return "Standing Timber Projects"
            case plSection:
                return "Purchased Logs"
            default:
                return "Unknown"
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getCSTProjects() -> Int {
         let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
         let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
         let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CSTProjects")
         var results = [AnyObject]()

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("There was an error loading the data. \(error)")
        }

        if (results.count > 0) {
            return results.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }


    func getPLProjects() -> Int {
        let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PLProjects")
        var results = [AnyObject]()

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("There was an error loading the data. \(error)")
        }

        if (results.count > 0) {
            return results.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do in that method is look up which instance you want to display. To do that, you should modify your `getCSTProjects` and `getPLProjects` methods to save the results of the fetch request instead of throwing them away. You'd do that by adding new attributes to the view controllers to hold the arrays. On a related note, you **really** do not want to call those methods from `tableView(tableView:, numberOfRowsInSection:)`, because that method can get called a lot. Doing fetches there pretty much guarantees poor performance.

To get a specific instance, look it up in one of the arrays you now have, using the `indexPath` argument to get the array index.

Once you have that specific instance, you need to look up values of the attributes you have declared on those Core Data entity types. What to put there depends on how your `CSTProjects` and `PLProjects` entities are defined and on whether you have created subclasses of `NSManagedObject` for them.

For example if your `CSTProjects` entity has a string attribute called `name` that you want to use as the title, and you **do not** have an `NSManagedObject` subclass, you could use this:

```
cell.textLabel!.text = currentInstance.value(forKey: "name") as? String
```

If you do have an NSManagedObject subclass (and it's always a good idea), this would be

```
cell.textLabel!.text = currentInstance.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to merge two entities (or tables) into a single fetchedResultsController, it would be easier to bring the data into a single table and access that.

If the tables are sufficiently similar, you could do this in a single table with a type code to differentiate the entries where you need to, for example using a filtered view to make the tables look like one type or the other in other parts of your code.  This would mean making any fields limited to one type optional so the other could ignore them.  Then the frc could use the code field as a section break.

Alternatively, if the tables are sufficiently different you could add a third table, say Projects, which had optional one-to-one links to the other two tables and drive the frc off of that third table using the links to populate fields in your tableView in the configure cell delegate method.

Besides making it easier to build the current frc structure, either of these approaches would make adding a third or fourth type much easier if your requirements expand in the future, and would avoid the complications that inevitably follow from bending an API to fit a use it wasn't designed for.